# Choosing ArcMap Geoprocessing tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing

I'm trying to find out what tool would be best suited to address a problem  that I have.

I am trying to find the most efficient route (least amount of pipe (footage) / most amount of houses provided with fire hydrant coverage (500 ft diameter buffer) for a water pipe through a sub division.

I know this is very vague, but what tool would be best suited to this?

I know find route would find the shortest route, but I also want to provide the most amount of coverage provided by the fire hydrants, so shortest route isn't necessarily the best suited

At the moment I am just putting my own buffers on a path that I myself think would serve the most houses with the least amount of buffer overlap from the hydrants, but I'm frustrating myself because there most probably is a better way of doing it (that I cant think of at the moment!)

Comment: Perhaps you could include a picture of what you're after to help us conceptualize what metric you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you are not really looking for tool(s) as there is none that will resolve that specific problem. You should rephrase your question asking for the best process to position your hydrant.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a way could be to find the smallest number of fire hydrant to cover all the building and position them, then use these points with the "Traveling Sales Person" algorithm to find the shortest length of pipe.

One first step could be to buffer your building by 500ft, you will get the area that must contain your hydrant (union of all buffer) and the best places where to put hydrant (places where 2 or more buffer overlap).

You could refine more by adding constraint (area where you cant lay pipe orb put a fire hydrant)